# Regex statement to cater for a field that can contain a blank value or numeric value in log files

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I am having an issue with an input.regex statement in my create table in hive query which results in part data from one field being partially populated into a different field.

The logs files contains a Request and a Reply transaction but in the Reply transaction, there is a column called Heartbeat which contains a timestamp in milliseconds which does not exist in the Request transactions.
The Hearbeat data can contain a timestamp with a decimal place and sometimes zero 
e.g '31.2498ms' or '0ms' which I cater for in my regex.

The issue is that it doesn't handle the Request transaction which does not contain a Heartbeat and in the data, it doesn't contain the extra spaces where the heartbeat would be, so the regex grabs the first few values from the SessionKey field and populates it into the heartbeat .

So the expected result is that the Heartbeat field contains no data for all Request transaction and the Sessionkey data is kept intact.

I have included below the regex and data sample and the screen shots from Rebular showing the issue highlighted in yellow.

**Regex**

```
(^[0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)   ([^ ]*)   ([0-9]* [0-9]* [0-9]*) ([^ ]*)(?:[:]) ([0-9]+.[0-9]+|[0-9]|)(?:ms |)([^ ]*)(?:[:])(.*$)
```

**Structure**

```
Version = 0 
EventTime = 20140625095038615 
LogTime = 20140625095038646 
SequenceNumber = 0000 
Level = 006 
InternalArea = 00/0000/000 
MachineName = LSEMPPRD  
ApplicationName = Nestra   
DiscardedMessageCount = 000 000000 00 
TranType = Reply: 
Heartbeat = 296.4057ms 
SessionKey = d594891a-6d9c-4b5c-913a-9dc302277534:
Message = <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><terminalSession xmlns:b="
```

**Sample Transaction types**

```
0 20140622104758792 20140622104758792 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Request: 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825: <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><terminalSession xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common" <b:SessionKey>17789cc9-6bc8-4c4b-85d2-b86b21af0fb3</b:SessionKey></terminalSession></GetInfo>
0 20140622104758792 20140622104758792 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Reply: 0ms 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825: <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetInfoResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Responses" </GetInfoResult></GetInfoResponse>
0 20140622104758792 20140622104758792 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Reply: 31.2498ms 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825: <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetInfoResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Responses" </GetInfoResult></GetInfoResponse>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your updated input lines:(4)

```
0 20140622104758792 20140622104758792 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Request: 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825: <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><terminalSession xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common" <b:SessionKey>17789cc9-6bc8-4c4b-85d2-b86b21af0fb3</b:SessionKey></terminalSession></GetInfo>
0 20140622104758792 20140622104758792 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Reply: 0ms 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825: <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetInfoResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Responses" </GetInfoResult></GetInfoResponse>
0 20140622104758792 20140622104758792 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Reply: 31.2498ms 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825: <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetInfoResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Responses" </GetInfoResult></GetInfoResponse>
0 20140621102140946 20140621102140946 0000 008 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 NesHost: Hello has stopped failing (after 1 failures).
```

single Regex to handle above 4 types of logs:

```
(^[0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)   ([^ ]*)   ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)(?:[:])([ \d*\.?\d+]+(?=ms)|)(?:ms|) ([^ ]+(?=\:)|)(?:\:|)(.*$)
```

verification @ http://rubular.com/: (refer above ans for line-1,2,3) snap of line-4

[image]

Comment: Love your work ramisetty, you have been so helpful, so thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `Reply:` and `Request:` fields always appear (one or the other) in these log transactions. You could use this fact in your regular expression using the `|` operator for either-or syntax:

```
(^[0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)   ([^ ]*)   ([0-9]* [0-9]* [0-9]*) (((Reply): ([0-9]+.[0-9]+|[0-9]|)(?:ms |))|(Request): )([^ ]*)(?:[:])(.*$)
```

I tested the above on your sample data using [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) (there are many online testers).  It shows the following output for the replace expression `$12, $13, $14, $15` that refers to captured group numbers:

```
, , Request, 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825
Reply, 0, , 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825
Reply, 31.2498, , 5a0a48b9-8b7d-4174-bdd5-55673affb825
```

So if capture group $12 is "Reply" then you know field `Heartbeat` is present in group $13, otherwise the record is a Request transaction.

Answer (score 0):

complete regex : (note spaces carefully)

```
(^[0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)   ([^ ]*)   ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)(?:[:])([ \d*\.?\d+]+(?=ms)|)(?:ms|) ([^ ]*)(?:[:])(.*$)
```

validation :

input: [image]

output: 
line-1

[image]

line-2

[image]

line-3

[image]

Comment: Hi ramisetty.vijay, your regex statement gives me the desired result but all of the fields for all 'Requests' are populated with an empty string as expected but all of the 'Reply' fields are appearing as NULL most likely due to the RegexSerDe in the hive query.
I am assuming if a value is substituted for the Request Heartbeat instead of a blank value that the rest if the data will be populated in the tables correctly.
So is there some way to populate a value of zero '0' for all Request Heartbeats in the regex? and will that resolve the NULL rows for all other transactions?

Comment: Root cause identified, a 4th Transaction that does not conform to the regex was detected in new logs loaded creating the 'NULL' rows. So regex needs to cater for the following as well `0 20140621102140946 20140621102140946 0000 008 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 NesHost: Hello has stopped failing (after 1 failures).` 'NesHost:' = Group 12 and 'Hello has stopped failing (after 1 failures).' = Group 15, so is it possible to cater for the 4 transaction types in the same regex even though the data structure is different?

Comment: pf my new answer you need in single regex. plz accept the same if helpful :)